# Xcode 15.2 ' No Such Module'

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

I have a added a package twilio_voice on the past it was okay and archiving well, But now it's not which kinda weird and after this day am having difficulties on this error in xcode, i've tried everything and searching a lot fixes this day but nothing works for me still same. Even configuring the xcode and framework search from xcode didn't help at all.

[image]

Comment: Did you run `pod install` within the `ios` directory?

Comment: Yes, Many times i even also deintegrate also then install or update , But maybe it’s on the package which the swift is not latest version

Answer (score 0):

Update the ruby and it work fine now

xcode 15.2
ruby 3.3.0
cocoapods 1.15.2

Answer (score 0):

I updated the ruby to 3.3.0 and reinstalled the cocoapods . It worked for me